# Can't hand exception

Tags: java, spring, exception

I use Spring and with the help of annotation @ControllerAdvice and created class for handling all exceptions.

```
 @EnableWebMvc
    @ControllerAdvice
    class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

private final MessageSource messages;

    private RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler(@Qualifier("messageSource") MessageSource messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

     @ExceptionHandler({ESInvalidValueException.class})
        public ResponseEntity<Object> handleValidation(final RuntimeException ex, final WebRequest request) {
            log.error("400 Status Code: " + ex.getMessage());
            Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
            final GenericResponse body = GenericResponse.error(
                    messages.getMessage("portNotValid", null, locale), 400);
            return handleExceptionInternal(ex, body, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
        }
    }
```

Also, I have created custom Exception that extends of AbstractPortalException:

```
public class ESInvalidValueException extends AbstractPortalException{

    public ESInvalidValueException(String message, int code) {

        super(message, code);
    }
}


public abstract class AbstractPortalException extends RuntimeException {

    private int code;

    AbstractPortalException() {
        super();
    }

    AbstractPortalException(final String message, final Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    AbstractPortalException(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    AbstractPortalException(final String message, int code) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
    }

    AbstractPortalException(final Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

And then I try to validate port number with the help of annotation @Valid in my controller.
Here my validation class:

```
@Log4j2
@Component
public class ESRequestDTOValidator implements Validator{

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return ElasticSearchLogRequest.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        log.debug("Validating: {}", target);
        ElasticSearchLogRequest form = (ElasticSearchLogRequest) target;
        validatePort(form);


    }

    private void validatePort(ElasticSearchLogRequest form) {
        String reg = "^((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})" +
                "|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0-9]{1,4}))$";
        if (!form.getPort().toString().matches(reg)) {
           throw new ESInvalidValueException("portNotValid", HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the problem: `messages.getMessage()` cant find message with such code "portNotValid". In the exception `ESInvalidValueException` I want to pass different messages for validation other fields and in `handleValidation()` method I want to handle all these exceptions according to messages. How I can implement such task? Maybe there is another aproach.

Answer (score 0):

this can not be achieved. checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20552196/3892213

> In your case your bean is behind a CGLIB proxy. It creates a subclass
>   of your bean and as the method has final modifier it can't change the
>   behavior of the original ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class to
>   insert a call to the bean behind - please check my other answer about
>   CGLIB.
>
> CGLIB proxy is a different object that delegates the method calls to
>   the original bean.
>
> Please note that it would not be possible to implement much of Spring
>   functionality only with subclassing i.e. without this separation of
>   objects. How would it work when singleton-scoped bean references a
>   session-scoped bean - obviously there are many session-scope beans and
>   only one singleton-scoped bean.

Instead of using spring bean, you can try using some private method to achieve this.